# Stereo Mix fails when using television speakers over HDMI

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, speakers

I use my TV as a display for my laptop, including the speakers (laptop has pitiful speakers). However, Stereo Mix becomes completely silent when the TV is the default sound device. So I can't stream audio or record audio in software, as it relies on Stereo Mix.

Is it possible to fix Stereo Mix so that it always outputs the system's audio even when outputting to different speakers? Is there a logical explanation for why it fails in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stereo Mix is a virtual sound source from your on-board soundcard.

HDMI is a separate soundcard and as such, when you record stereo mix, it records silence, because it is recording from a another sound card than the sound is actually coming from.

You may be able to solve the problem by putting an audio cable from the headphone jack of the tv to the line-input of your soundcard, so it gets sound, then you can either record from line-in (recommended) or stereo mix to solve the issue. A much better approach is to not use the HDMI soundcard, but your onboard soundcard, and simply hook up a set of speakers to your laptop. This way, you can also use things like ASIO4All if you want to create music and other streaming stuff. You might be able to find a cable that has HDMI and a separate audio jack cable to hdmi, so you can connect the audio cable into your laptop's headphone jack to get sound that way. And if that doesn't exist, you might be able to make such a cable yourself.

It is also possible to do this using software, but I only know paid software that can do this: Virtual Audio Cable. You can use this to copy sound from one source to another and create a virtual cable so you can create a stereo mix for the HDMI cable to record. But it is CPU intensive and can cause audio issues, so this is more of a last-resort solution.